# How/why does display:table affect div width?

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, css-tables

I'm noticing that `display:table` on a div will cause its width calculation to have rounding issues, which is odd because I am sizing at 100%.

http://jsbin.com/obidun/2/edit

Note that the upper section has a div with width of 55%, with a nested display:table div of width 100%.  The nested div does not extend to the edge of its parent (note the white bleed-through of the parent div).

The lower section is exactly the same, except the nested div is not set to `display:table`, and there is no bleed through.

Why does `display:table` affect the width calculation, especially at 100%?  Is there a way for me to work around this?  My current thought is to just set the width to 101% and set overflow to hidden...

Note: I am using Chrome.  IE seems to be okay, at least at the given size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Percentage units](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2012/02/17/sub-pixel-rendering-and-the-css-object-model.aspx) are converted to pixels [internally](http://www.brunildo.org/test/percwidth2.pl) and each browser does it differently. If the solution works today, go with it, but be aware it may not apply [tomorrow](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60318).